# Recursive with square root C++

Tags: c++

```
float pkt(float x, int n) {
  float result;
  if (n == 0) {
    result = 1;
  } else {
    result = (pkt(x, n - 1) * x) + sqrt(x);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Assume that I insert 4 and 2.
I want count it like this:

[image]

But the result is 26 instead 18. 
The formula is (x^n)+√x.

Comment: The code you posted is not the code you are using.

Comment: hint: at each recursion call you add `sqrt(x)` (different x each time of course)

Comment: What's the correspondence between your recursive code and the linked formula?

Comment: Is the formula `x^n + x^(1/n)` or is it `x^n + x^(1/2)`? (where `a^b` means "a to the power of b", note that `a^(1/m)` is the m-th root of `a`)

Comment: What I mean is : (x^n)+√x
@TobiMcNamobi

Comment: Such formula doesn't need any recursion, only two functions one for *power* and one for *square root*. The *power* function can be implemented recursively but it is not needed.

Comment: @dlask You might be right, but I want to understand more about recursive, that's all.

Comment: @Embek Then focus your attention to the only recursive function, which is the `power` function there.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting 26 because that's what your code says to do.

Building up from `pkt(4.0,0)` to `pkt(4.0,1)` to `pkt(4.0,2)` yields

```
pkt(4.0,0) -> 1.0
pkt(4.0,1) -> pkt(4.0,0)*4.0 + sqrt(4.0) = 1.0*4.0 + 2.0 = 6.0
pkt(4.0,2) -> pkt(4.0,1)*4.0 + sqrt(4.0) = 6.0*4.0 + 2.0 = 26.0
```

Sans the recursion, your function is the equivalent of

```
float pkt_no_recursion (float x, int n)
{
   if (x == 1.0)
   {
      return float(n) + 1.0f;
   }
   else
   {
      float pow_x_n = std::pow(x,n);
      float sqrt_x = std::sqrt(x);
      return (pow_x_n*(x+sqrt_x) - (pow_x_n+sqrt_x)) / (x - 1.0f);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is the function `sr` defined? Is this what you are after? Possibly replace `powerOf` by standard function `powf` (or make `powerOf` recursive if that is a requirement).

```
float powerOf(float x, int n) {
  float res = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    res *= x;
  }
  return res;
}

float pangkat (float x, int n) {
  return powerOf(x, n) + sqrtf(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function will give `26` as the answer because in this statement:

```
  result = (pkt(x, n - 1) * x) + sqrt(x);
```

you return the `result` as the `sum` of the power equation you are attempting and the `sqrt`. This `sqrt` will get included everytime you return the result, whereas it is only required in the end.

So instead, move the `sqrt` to where it is being called, instead of including it in every recursive call.

```
result = (pkt(x, n - 1) * x) ;
```

And call the function as:

```
pkt(4,2)+ sqrt(4);
```

[An example](http://ideone.com/3bThGm)